# where is socket header in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I compile my simple prog with `#include <sys/socket.h>` but there's none of this file. 
Where is it, I just start coding in linux and I have no idea where is it . Or do we need to download it online .

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to have a look at Boost::Asio. It's cross-platform *and* comes with proper C++ interfaces (which, in my book, beats a Unix-specific C API). YMMV.

Comment: Thanks DevSolar for more information and it does help :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In case you have installed manual pages, the first stop should be `man socket`.

Without manual pages you could call

```
find /usr/include -name socket.h
```

which outputs

```
/usr/include/asm/socket.h
/usr/include/sys/socket.h
/usr/include/bits/socket.h
/usr/include/linux/socket.h
```

on my system, the one to include is `sys/socket.h` .

Also see the [Single UNIX Specification](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/syssocket.h.html).

Comment: thanks there's another place, the find tool and include folder is useful :)

Answer (score 3):

On a fresh Linux, for example, Ubuntu X86-64, while there is no gcc installed, there is no `socket.h` headers, while installed gcc, you can `find` it under `/usr/include`, for me, the output is:

```
$ find /usr/include/ -name socket.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/socket.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h
/usr/include/linux/socket.h
```

Comment: On Debian and it's derivates (Ubuntu, ...) are basic header files (including `sys/socket.h`) in package `libc6-dev`. The place under `/usr/include` is arch dependent.

Answer (score 2):

```
man socket
```

should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
```

See this :

http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

Answer (score 0):

It should be `#include <sys/socket.h>`. You may also need to include `sys/types.h`.

But if that's failing, can you give a short snippet of source, including what files you're #include'ing and how, and what error message(s) you're getting?